# Why does `T&&` not stick?

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue, lvalue, xvalue

Say I have the following functions:

```
void f2(int&& i)
{
    puts("f2(int&& i)");
}

void f(int&& i)
{
    puts("f(int&& i)");
    f2(i);
}
```

The compiler error emitted is:

> error C2664: 'void f2(int &&)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'int &&'

> message : You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference

It works if you cast to `int&&` *again* with another call to `std::move()`:

```
void f(int&& i)
{
    puts("f(int&& i)");
    f2(std::move(i));
}
```

But that shouldn't be necessary should it? It looks to me that the variable received by `f(int&& i)` is an xvalue. If `f` receives `int&&`, so we should just be able to pass that along, no?

How is the `int&&` received by `f` still an lvalue?

Comment: Hmm, your title is actually a much better description of the problem than the target's title. Thanks for the question.

Comment: `f2()` expects an rvalue. But inside of `f()`, `i` received an rvalue, but is not itself an rvalue. Thus why the cast via `std::move()` is needed.

Comment: The general rule of thumb (not completely correct, but close enough) is:  if it has a *name* it's an lvalue.  `i` is a name, ergo, lvalue.